# Раскодировать html ссылку из base64

Tags: base64, htmlspecialchars, php, get

Добрый день!

Есть входящий GET параметр

```
?url=aHR0cDovL2dvb2dsZS5jb20udWE/cGFyYW1zPTE=
```

Что является http://google.com.ua?params=1

Как на php его раскодировать чтобы читало символы "?=/"?

Таким способом не выходит.

```
$url = base64_decode($_GET['url']);
```

Да и для защиты лучше htmlspecialchars использовать.

Как сделать грамотно, подскажите новичку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Таким способом не выходит.
>
> ```
> $url = base64_decode($_GET['url']);
> ```

Нужно строку `$_GET['url']` разбить на подстроки по символу "/" и каждую подстроку декодировать

```
<?php
$decoded = array();
$urlParts = explode('/', $_GET['url']); // разбить части
foreach($urlParts as $str)
    $decoded[] = base64_decode($str); // расшифровать части
$decoded = implode('/', $decoded); // склеить части обратно
?>
```

Comment: я полностью новичок, можете написать кодом?

Comment: заработало! спасибо)